# Execute script on windows event no result timed script yes

Tags: events, dos, wsh

I have a script that normally executes every 5 minutes.
It starts a Photoshop session and treats pictures in a folder.
This works but I need to stay logged in to the PC.
I tried with the setting Run logged on or not.

I then created a windows task based on a event 4663 and/or 5145.
When a file now arrives in the folder the event fires the script I even see Photoshop launching, but no pictures is treated.
It's the same script so I don't know why this is the case..

Regards
Guy

Comment: Why is this tagged as Bash?  Are you really running it in Bash?

Comment: The case could be... Another user / starting directory / working directory / etc.  All could change when the script is executed from Task Manager...